# why PackageOperation01 folder not created in andriod-sdk automantically

Tags: android, gradle, jenkins

Compiling the Andriod app using the Jenkins pipeline fails with an error that PackageOperation01/build-tools_r30.0.1-linux.zip is not found.

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.1: /usr/lib/android-sdk/.temp/PackageOperation01/build-tools_r30.0.1-linux.zip.:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/lib/android-sdk/.temp/PackageOperation01/build-tools_r30.0.1-linux.zip

I checked the directory and the folder is missing.

I have already

1. Download and install Andriod SDK - sudo  wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip
2. unzip commandlinetools
3. set export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk/, export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin, and export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
4. Give users access to the folder and accept license.